# Xbox 360 Wireless Controller's dongle not working for Windows 10

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, windows-10

The receiver looks exactly like this: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Official-Wireless-Gaming-Receiver-Windows/dp/B000MGVAAQ

When I plug it, the slit-like LED light does not turn on.

When I turn my Xbox 360 wireless controller on, it blinks normally, and then I press that synchronization button, it blinks in a circular way.  So I guess the controller is great, but it's just that the receiver that's not turning on.

This is a fresh Windows 10 installation.

S.O.S.

---

## Updates

- Opened the case, and tested the USB cable for continuity, and the USB cable is perfectly functional.
- But, then, I thought, maybe the connector pins are not good enough for the USB socket in my PC, so I butchered it, replaced its head with a new one (new pins).

Still fails.  No LED turns on when I plug the thing in.

I guess now there is something failing in the circuitry of this receiver.

The circuitry is too small.  I cannot replace it.  So **VERY UNFORTUNATELY** looks that I need to buy a new one :/..  ****MEGASIGH****.

Comment: These receivers are prone to blowing a fuse. I was able to resurrect one of mine by opening it up and shorting the fuse, as described in the iFixit guide: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Microsoft+Xbox+360+Wireless+Gaming+Receiver+fuse+replacement/118338

Comment: WHAT!!! This little thing has another little fuse?  ITSELF IS A FUSE ALREADY, why have another fuse?  I don't get this.  Anyway, thank you very much, but sadly it's too late, and I already butchered mine + ordered a new :(  I wish I could read your comment earlier.

Comment: I tried your solution.  It worked!! I'm going to cancel my order :)  Thanks.  Please add your comment as an answer so that I smash the green tick button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Xbox 360 Wireless Gaming Receiver for Windows" ([product page](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/accessories/xbox-360-wireless-gaming-receiver-windows)) is prone to blowing the F1 fuse ([seen here](https://icptjacksparrow.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/11.jpg)), after which it stops working completely. The reason the fuse fails is thought to be from overheating.

If your receiver has failed in this way, it can be fixed by replacing the faulty fuse. If you don't have a replacement fuse or aren't comfortable soldering surface mount components, you can try bridging the contacts with solder as a temporary fix. In general it's not safe to bypass a fuse in this way and this could result in damage to the receiver or the host it's plugged into.

Thanks to ICptJackSparrow for his repair guide, this is where I first learned of the issue and how to fix it:

https://replayproject.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/how-to-repair-microsoft-xbox-360™-wireless-gaming-receiver-for-windows®/

iFixit also has an excellent guide for this repair:

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Microsoft+Xbox+360+Wireless+Gaming+Receiver+fuse+replacement/118338

If you choose to bypass the fuse rather than replace it, keep in mind that the receiver is now at greater risk of overheating and should be considered a potential fire hazard. Make sure it gets plenty of air flow and avoid leaving it plugged in when not in use.

Comment: Thank you very much!  That solved it and saved my money.  I made only one thing differently:  instead of using U shaped wire over the faulty fuse, I put solder over the top of the fuse.  So, the fuse is now buried underneath a lump of solder.  I find my approach easier, as the fuse is tiny, and putting a U shaped wire around it requires more time that is eventually more expensive than putting extra solder.  I personally found it cheaper to put a lump of solder over the fuse, and bury the fuse underneath.

Comment: Admittedly, if time goes back, I'll 1st remove the fuse, and put a line of solder in its place.  The reason I made the lump over the fuse was by accident, as I was trying to put a U-shaped wire, and I failed, so I ended up burying the fuse under a lump of solder.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I wonder, why is no one removing the fault fuse and putting a line of solder?  Every link seems to be using a U shaped wire.  I think what they do is needless complexity.  But I am open to hear their view.

Comment: @caveman: It might be because removing the fuse requires some soldering experience, but I agree it's the simplest solution if one is comfortable with it. Another simple solution is to just cover the fuse with solder, thereby bypassing it.

Comment: Ya that's what I did (I described it in my comment earlier; i.e. burying the fuse).  It happened by accident as I tried to do the U shape nonsense.