# How can I connect my wireless Xbox 360 controllers to Windows 10?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, windows-10

I have two wireless Xbox 360 controllers and a wireless receiver, connected to a Windows 10 PC. All were previously working, and [the receiver light is working normally](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/355520/xbox-360-wireless-controllers-dongle-not-working-for-windows-10).

However, the controllers and receiver don't seem to find each other any more. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to happen now and then after a Windows 10 update. The solution is to force your machine to recognize the device.

- Open the Device Manager
- Under "Other devices", locate "Unknown device"
- Right-click and select "Update driver software..."
- Select "Browse my computer"
- Select "Let me pick"
- Select " Xbox 360 peripherals"
- From the driver list select "Xbox 360 wirelesss receiver 10.x" (not 2.x)
- Click "Next"
- Accept the warning

Your wireless receiver should now work again, and it should detect your controllers.

Source (video tutorial):